# Adding dashboard to Apple Wallet Pass like Apple Card

Tags: ios, wallet

I am currently trying to find if it is possible to create a dashboard to my companies loyalty pass, similar to the one that Apple has created for their own Apple Card.

[image]

I have been able to add just a text on the card that updates whenever I send the notification, but I am looking to display more stats about customers purchases. I have not been successful in finding guidance about this on documentation, so it could be that Apple doesn't allow that yet to anyone else. Is my idea possible, if so how to add GUI elements under the pass?